# Limit points of S = $\{\frac{1}{n}, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, what about irrationals?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I've been thinking about limit points and irrationals. Why is there not an irrational just a bit bigger than zero such that it is not in the set S and for every $\delta > 0$ it contains some element of S? For that matter why are there not irrationals between every $\frac{1}{n}$ that act as limit points?

Comment: there is only one limit point for that sequence: zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us imagine such an irrational $w$, as you say close to $0$ (or at least less than $1$) and bigger than $0$.  Then there is a natural number $k$ such that $\frac{1}{k}\lt w$.

The fact that there is such an $k$ is called the *Archimedean Property* of the reals. Informally, it says that there are no infinitesimally small non-zero quantities.  We omit the proof that the reals have the Archimedean property, but can sketch a proof on request. One of the usual proofs uses the least upper bound property.

Let $N$ be the largest natural number such that $\frac{1}{N}\le w$. By our assumptions, $N\gt 1$ and $w$ is *strictly between* $\frac{1}{N}$ and $\frac{1}{N-1}$.

Let $\epsilon=\min(w-\frac{1}{N}, \frac{1}{N-1}-w)$. Then for all integers $k$, we have $\left|w-\frac{1}{k}\right|\ge \epsilon$. This shows that $w$ cannot be a limit point of $S$.

Comment: This is very helpful.

Comment: I was afraid I was being a little too formal. Note that the fact $w$ is irrational was not used in the proof, the only assumption we really need on $w$ is that it is a non-zero quantity not of the shape $\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: No the proof is exactly what I needed to be convinced.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that 
$$\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1} = \frac{1}{n(n+1)}.$$
You can certainly take any irrational between these two numbers and choose a $\delta > 0$ small enough so that the ball with radius $\delta$ doesn't contain either of those two numbers. Thus, if you can find one open set that contains the potential limit point, but does not intersect the set, that's enough to show that it's not a limit point. Hopefully this answers both of your questions.

Comment: Yes that makes perfect sense. I guess it is hard for me to visualize the idea that there is no irrational number on the very edge of either of the two numbers you mention for which the ball would not include it, but one of the rationals.

Comment: Keep in mind that the irrationals are limit points of the $\textit{rationals}$, but not the set that you've given. The rationals are dense in the reals, but your set is not.

Comment: Right. I think that was also confusing me, since I knew they *could* be limit points.